# Keyboard hidden after becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

I'm bringing focus to a UITextView after setting its **.hidden** property to NO. When I set the [textView becomeFirstResponder] the textView gets the little typing cursor, but the keyboard remains hidden. Any idea why? If it helps, the main view is a modal view that a UINavigationController is presenting.

EDIT: Here's the method that gets called:

```
- (void)show_comment_elements {

    toolbar.hidden = YES;
    main_table.hidden = YES;
    add_comment_table.hidden = NO;
    comment_text.hidden = NO;

    [comment_text becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: frustration]

Comment: some code would be useful too

Comment: Does this help - http://bcaccinolo.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/uitextfield-with-the-keyboard-automagically/ - assuming your modal view controller is being pushed and you want the keyboard to be shown immediately.

Comment: How did you fix this? I have been having a similar problem, posting your solution would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you've verified that your method is getting invoked after the view is placed on-screen.

From the docs....

> A responder object only becomes the
>   first responder if the current
>   responder can resign first-responder
>   status (canResignFirstResponder) and
>   the new responder can become first
>   responder.
>
> You may call this method to make a
>   responder object such as a view the
>   first responder. However, you should
>   only call it on that view if it is
>   part of a view hierarchy. If the
>   view’s window property holds a
>   UIWindow object, it has been installed
>   in a view hierarchy; if it returns
>   nil, the view is detached from any
>   hierarchy.

So:

1. Can you confirm that the current responder when your method is invoked can resign first-responder status?
2. Your view appears to be in the view hierarchy if it is displaying from the screen shot.  If the screen-shot is from IB, then test that the view's window property is not nil.
3. Make sure the view is editable -- if(comment_text.isEditable) or it will not accept first responder status.
4. Try adding [comment_text setNeedsDisplay] to force a re-fresh with the view set as first responder.

If none of this works, post some more code (such as where the method is being called from).

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs when you modify the `nextResponder` on some object in the chain, so that the responder chain does not go to the `UIWindow`.